# Django UpdateView not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the UpdateView of django but for some reason it does not work.

```
(URL.py)
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
app_name='profiles'
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',views.DetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
url(r'^task/add/$',views.TaskCreate.as_view(),name='task-add'),
url(r'^task/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',views.TaskUpdate.as_view(), name='task-update'),
url(r'^task/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$',views.TaskDelete.as_view(), name='task-delete'),]
```

Below is my Html file in which I am trying to add a "Edit" link which will redirect to the UpdateView.

```
(Details.PY this already has the second url mapped)
{% extends 'profiles/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<H3>The total efforts are {{datamain.efforts}} {{datamain.status}} hours.</H3>

<a href="{% url 'profiles:task-update' %}">Edit</a>
   {% endblock %}
```

Below is the Views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'profiles/index.html'
def get_queryset(self):
    return Datamain.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Datamain
    template_name = 'profiles/details.html'

class TaskCreate(CreateView):
    model=Datamain
    fields=['main_task','date_time','efforts','status']

class TaskUpdate(UpdateView):
    model=Datamain
    fields=['main_task','date_time','efforts','status']

class TaskDelete(DeleteView):
    model=Datamain
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profiles:index')
    fields=['main_task','date_time','efforts','status']
```

When I run it and go to the page , it shows error "no reverse match"

Comment: What's the url in the browser?

Comment: @EvansMurithi "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/2" , now the crazy thing is that if i use "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/task/2" it works and goes to the edit page but I have to manually add the "task" in the url which is why i used a link to do the same.

Comment: This is because, `/home/task/2` matches the url pattern `url(r'^task/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',views.TaskUpdate.as_view(), name='task-update'),`. `/home/2` will match `url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',views.DetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),`

Comment: @EvansMurithi , THank you for your input, I figured that out but my question is why doesnt the same work when i put it in a link using a <a href> tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to pass url argument `pk` try this:

```
<a href="{% url 'profiles:task-update' pk=datamain.id %}">Edit</a>
```